# How to stop a sfml clock In C++ to stop a function from happening

Tags: c++, time.h

I am trying to stop A clock after 1 of the players reaches a score of 10 so the game stops and puts a button they can press one to play again I know this is a farfetched question because of stopping the clock but can anyone help me.I am confused because there is no stop function on the clock in time.h.

I tried searching this topic up but i got different ways of doing it that would not suit my code.

Here is my code -->> https://hastebin.com/share/uwuvejakih.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace sf;

int N = 30, M = 20;
int N1 = 30, M1 = 20;
int size = 16;
int scoreB = 0, scoreR = 0;

int w = size * N;
int h = size * M;

int dir, dir1, num = 4, num1 = 4;

sf::Text bScore;
std::ostringstream BsScore;
sf::Font arial;
std::ostringstream RsScore;
sf::Text rScore;
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(w, h), "Snake Game!");
struct Snake
{
    int x, y;
}  s[100];
struct Snake2
{
    int x1, y1;
}  s1[100];

struct Fruit
{
    int x, y;
} f;

struct Fruit1
{
    int x1, y1;
} f1;

void Tick3();
void Tick4();

void Tick()
{
    for (int i = num; i > 0; --i)
    {
        s[i].x = s[i - 1].x; s[i].y = s[i - 1].y;
    }

    if (dir == 0) s[0].y += 1;
    if (dir == 1) s[0].x -= 1;
    if (dir == 2) s[0].x += 1;
    if (dir == 3) s[0].y -= 1;

    if ((s[0].x == f.x) && (s[0].y == f.y))
    {
        Tick4();
    }

    if (s[0].x > N) s[0].x = 0;  if (s[0].x < 0) s[0].x = N;
    if (s[0].y > M) s[0].y = 0;  if (s[0].y < 0) s[0].y = M;

    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
        if (s[0].x == s[i].x && s[0].y == s[i].y)
        {
            num = i;
            scoreR = num;
            RsScore.str("");
            rScore.setString(RsScore.str());
            window.draw(rScore);
            RsScore << scoreR;
            rScore.setString(RsScore.str());
        }

}

void Tick2()
{
    for (int i = num1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        s1[i].x1 = s1[i - 1].x1; s1[i].y1 = s1[i - 1].y1;
    }


    if (dir1 == 0) s1[0].y1 += 1;
    if (dir1 == 1) s1[0].x1 -= 1;
    if (dir1 == 2) s1[0].x1 += 1;
    if (dir1 == 3) s1[0].y1 -= 1;

    if ((s1[0].x1 == f1.x1) && (s1[0].y1 == f1.y1))
    {
        Tick3();
    }

    if (s1[0].x1 > N1) s1[0].x1 = 0;  if (s1[0].x1 < 0) s1[0].x1 = N1;
    if (s1[0].y1 > M1) s1[0].y1 = 0;  if (s1[0].y1 < 0) s1[0].y1 = M1;

    for (int i = 1; i < num1; i++)
        if (s1[0].x1 == s1[i].x1 && s1[0].y1 == s1[i].y1)
        {
            num1 = i;
            scoreB = num1;
            BsScore.str("");
            bScore.setString(BsScore.str());
            window.draw(bScore);
            BsScore << scoreB;
            bScore.setString(BsScore.str());
        }
}

void Tick3()
{
    num1++; f1.x1 = rand() % N1; f1.y1 = rand() % M1;
    scoreB++;
    BsScore.str("");
    bScore.setString(BsScore.str());
    window.draw(bScore);
    BsScore << scoreB;
    bScore.setString(BsScore.str());
}

void Tick4()
{

    num++; f.x = rand() % N; f.y = rand() % M;
    scoreR++;
    RsScore.str("");
    rScore.setString(RsScore.str());
    window.draw(rScore);
    RsScore << scoreR;
    rScore.setString(RsScore.str());

}

int main()
{

    arial.loadFromFile("ARIAL.TTF");


    BsScore << scoreB;

    bScore.setFont(arial);
    bScore.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    bScore.setCharacterSize(30);
    bScore.setPosition({ 10, 10 });
    bScore.setFont(arial);
    bScore.setString(BsScore.str());


    RsScore << scoreR;
    rScore.setFont(arial);
    rScore.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    rScore.setCharacterSize(30);
    rScore.setPosition({ 450, 10 });
    rScore.setFont(arial);
    rScore.setString(RsScore.str());


    srand(time(0));



    Texture t1, t2, t3, t4;
    t1.loadFromFile("images/white.png");
    t2.loadFromFile("images/red.png");
    t3.loadFromFile("images/green.png");
    t4.loadFromFile("images/blue.png");
    Sprite sprite1(t1);
    Sprite sprite2(t2);
    Sprite sprite3(t3);
    Sprite sprite4(t4);
    Clock clock;
    Clock clock1;
    Clock clock2;
    Clock clock3;
    float timer = 0, delay = 0.1;
    float timer1 = 0;
    float timer2 = 0;
    float timer3 = 0;
    f.x = 10;
    f.y = 10;
    f1.x1 = 15;
    f1.y1 = 15;



    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        clock.restart();
        timer += time;

        float time1 = clock1.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        clock1.restart();
        timer1 += time1;



        Event e;
        while (window.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if (e.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)) dir = 1;
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) dir = 2;
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up)) dir = 3;
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down)) dir = 0;
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) dir1 = 1;
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D)) dir1 = 2;
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W)) dir1 = 3;
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S)) dir1 = 0;

        if (timer > delay) { timer = 0; Tick(); }
        if (timer1 > delay) { timer1 = 0; Tick2(); }

        ////// draw  ///////
        window.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            {
                sprite1.setPosition(i * size, j * size);  window.draw(sprite1);
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            sprite2.setPosition(s[i].x * size, s[i].y * size);  window.draw(sprite2);


        }


        for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
        {
            sprite4.setPosition(s1[i].x1 * size, s1[i].y1 * size);  window.draw(sprite4);;
        }

        sprite2.setPosition(f.x * size, f.y * size);  window.draw(sprite2);
        sprite4.setPosition(f1.x1 * size, f1.y1 * size);  window.draw(sprite4);

        if (scoreB == 10)
        {
            std::ostringstream Winner;
            Winner << "Blue Wins!";
            sf::Text Winb;
            Winb.setFont(arial);
            Winb.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
            Winb.setCharacterSize(40);
            Winb.setPosition({ 150, 250 });
            Winb.setFont(arial);
            Winb.setString(Winner.str());

            window.draw(Winb);
            
        }

        if (scoreR == 10)
        {
            std::ostringstream Winner;
            Winner << "Red Wins!";
            sf::Text Winr;
            Winr.setFont(arial);
            Winr.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
            Winr.setCharacterSize(40);
            Winr.setPosition({ 150, 250 });
            Winr.setFont(arial);
            Winr.setString(Winner.str());

            window.draw(Winr);



        }



        window.draw(bScore);
        window.draw(rScore);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions should be self contained and not rely on external links. Why do you want to stop the system clock? Seems rather heavy handed way to stop some timer in your program

Comment: Neither C++ <time.h> nor <ctime> nor <chrono> have any stopwatch-like class named `Clock`.  It must be coming from SFML.

Comment: i want to stop it because it the one the makes the snake go forward every second and it uses time and timer to check if  any of the thing in tick happen and it checks the every second that is why so i can stop the game and ask if the want to play again using a button

Comment: Try searching for SFML results (`sf::Clock`), not time.h

Comment: thanks Ben i in fact didn't know that

Comment: i found my own post while searching

Comment: If you can't *stop* the clock, then you could just set a variable that means "ignore the clock" and then once you don't want to ignore the clock any more, note it's current value and continue from there.. there are many ways to handle the situation.

Comment: I would advice you to watch this very good talk: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a global flag (`game_running` might be a good name) and then use it to ignore the passage of time.

e.g.

```
if (game_running) { // add this line
    float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    clock.restart();
    timer += time;

    float time1 = clock1.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    clock1.restart();
    timer1 += time1;
}
```

The 6 lines in the middle were already part of your `main` function, this just adds a way to skip over them.

There's also no good reason to have two separate `sf::Clock` objects there, you can use one to update both intervals, like

```
if (game_running) {
    float time = clock.restart().asSeconds();
    timer += time;
    timer1 += time;
}
```

After making that change, "stopping the passage of time" is just `game_running = false;` and starting it again for a new game is `timer = timer1 = 0; clock.restart(); game_running = true;`

Comment: i need the 2 clocks because there are 2 players...

Comment: @KariemDevkariem: You need two play clocks, which you named `timer` and `timer1`.  You don't need two "ask the OS about the time" objects, which is what your `sf::Clock clock;` is.

Comment: also  the code you gave me does not work

Comment: @KariemDevkariem The code posted in this answer demonstrates why you don't need two clocks and how a flag can be used to "ignore the clock" (like stopping it). If it doesn't work for you then you may need to tweak it a bit, but the theory behind the answer is sound.